# Programming / memory / logical issue in code

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, memory-management

Can you tell me is there any thing wrong in the code, my application is crashing randomly
I cannot find any possible logical or memory error, please help as this is going out of my scope.

```
#define __FN__ "CGD9_gd_ParseAddFieldsProC"
int CGD9_gd_ParseAddFieldsProC (CGD_gd_ParseAddFields_Iparam_t *i_param_st_p)
{

   t_gd9adfld_t *p_ext_fields_s = NULL;
   t_gd9sbdat_t *p_buff =
                  ( t_gd9sbdat_t * )( i_param_st_p->i_add_fields_st );

   Trace(__FN__);

   DEBUG_GD_1("\n\n Function %s - started. \n\n", __FN__);

   if(*(i_param_st_p->o_add_fields) == NULL) {
     ERR_Report_1(DGD_ERR_IN_FUNCTION,
     __FN__ "ERROR - program will crash, input extended struct\
has not been initialized!");

     ERR_Report_1(DGD_ERR_IN_FUNCTION, __FN__\
"Check that exit point CMI9_auxc_A_GUIDING_init_forProc \
is used in GD table!");

    fflush(NULL);
    return FAILURE;
   }

   p_ext_fields_s = *(i_param_st_p->o_add_fields);

   memset ( p_ext_fields_s, ' ', sizeof (t_gd9adfld_t));

/* Copy all extended fields from GD tables to buffer one by one*/

        memcpy(&p_ext_fields_s->rowid,
          &p_buff[i_param_st_p->output_index].rowid,
          sizeof(p_buff[i_param_st_p->output_index].rowid));

    memset(p_ext_fields_s->rowid,'0',18);


        memcpy(&p_ext_fields_s->l9_legacy_prod_type,
          &p_buff[i_param_st_p->output_index].l9_legacy_prod_type,
          sizeof(p_ext_fields_s->l9_legacy_prod_type));


   /* Free the memory allocated for extended fields */

   free(i_param_st_p -> i_add_fields_st);
   i_param_st_p -> i_add_fields_st = NULL;

   DEBUG_GD_1("\n\n Function %s - completed successuflly. \n\n", __FN__);

   return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Most compilers predefine a macro with the function name for you - usually `__FUNCTION__` or something close.  That would at least save you from doing it yourself.

Comment: Your debugger should tell you which line is crashing, and give you a backtrace to find out how you got to that state.  What have you done so far?

Comment: an exit point was written in the upper layer and from there i have used it to create my own code in the below layer. 

The pstack :
ffffffff6e908e84 CGD9_gd_ParseAddFieldsProC (ffffffff427eecd8, 0, 1144963b0, 10e318c90, 1144963b0, ffffffff427ef098) + 13c

Comment: bad tag on "objective-c" - this is straight up C world and memory management.

Answer (score 3):

Shot in the dark:

You're using

```
memcpy(&p_ext_fields_s->rowid ...
```

but

`memset(p_ext_fields_s->rowid`,...

So perhaps it should be

`memset(&p_ext_fields_s->rowid`,

instead? But if this really was the problem, I would expect it to not randomly crash, but crash every single time...

Comment: it is crashing every single time. but some times it run for 3 hrs and some times only for 2 min

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use **sizeof()** in the first case and then constant size (**18**) in the second?

```
memcpy(&p_ext_fields_s->rowid,
  &p_buff[i_param_st_p->output_index].rowid,
  sizeof(p_buff[i_param_st_p->output_index].rowid));

memset(p_ext_fields_s->rowid,'0',18);
```

PS
I'd propose run your code with memory checking tool (as I suspect memory corruptions).

Comment: one thing i want to confirm looking at the above post should the code be like this:

  memset(&p_ext_fields_s->rowid,'0',sizeof(p_buff[i_param_st_p->output_index].rowid));

Comment: Try excluding lines step by step. Of course, you'll miss some functionality, but you'll be able to identify the failing piece of code. For example flush(null) can be dropped, free() calls can be dropped (of course, it'll be a memory leak, but it might help to find the reason of crashing).

Answer (score 0):

The code is crashing to free memory allocation:

```
free(i_param_st_p -> i_add_fields_st);
```

What is wrong in tht :< ?